# AmazonS3Builder produces valid AmazonS3 object but a null is ultimately returned

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm using the AWS Java SDK v1 and I'm trying to create an AmazonS3 instance using the builder. I'm following the guide in the AWS documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) and passing explicit credentials using a BasicAWSCredentials object. When the builder builds, I get a null client back to `s3Client` which is where I'm storing the instance, and I'm not sure why. There are no errors thrown or caught by the try-catch blocks. Here is how I am making the connection:

```
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = null;
    try {
        awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(settings.getAccessKey(), settings.getSecretKey());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3Client.builder()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(s3Client);
```

I have stepped through it with the Eclipse debugger and it looks like the `build()` call is actually returning a valid AmazonS3Client instance, but then before this reference is returned back to the `s3Client` variable, there's a step in which `checkPackageAccess()` is called, and this return value is what is being returned back for some reason. On further inspection I found that `checkPackageAccess()` is a method in the java.lang.ClassLoader that's being called by the JVM, and it has a void return type. In my application, it looks like there's no default SecurityManager set, so there's no other function called inside the ClassLoader's `checkPackageAccess()` method.

I'm a bit confused by this behavior. My JRE is 1.8. So far as I understand, the ClassLoader is always called when looking for a class definition, but why would it be called after a class has already been instantiated, and why is the original return value of the `build()` function not coming back to the caller context? In this case, the debugger shows a valid AmazonS3Client object exists and is returned by the call to `build()` even before the checkPackageAccess call.

I've made an AmazonRedshift instance with almost identical code in the same project previously, and that worked without a hitch, so I'm quite positive the problem is with the AmazonS3 class or the builder, but I'm not sure where and I'm not seeing any errors or strange prints.

Code used for making a similar connection to Amazon Redshift:

```
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = null;
    try {
        awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        client = AmazonRedshiftClientBuilder.standard()
                                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(client);
```

Has anyone debugged this kind of issue before? What can I do to resolve this and get back a valid instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being far more fundamental. I feel almost embarrassed to write this. I had to get a second pair of eyes on my code to find it, but I was redeclaring the s3Client within the try block.

```
private AmazonS3 s3Client = null;
```

...

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = null;
try {
    awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(settings.getAccessKey(), settings.getSecretKey());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
}

try {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3Client.builder()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .build();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(s3Client);
```

By the time it reached the code that actually used the AmazonS3 object, the local variable holding a reference to it had already passed out of scope. Can't believe I didn't catch this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to constructing your builder from its own class rather than from the S3Client method `builder()`?  The following code, which parallels your Redshift case, is working okay for me.

```
    static final String BUCKET_NAME = "hello-world";

    /** Creates bucket
    @param args Command line arguments*/
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

            AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();

            CreateBucketRequest request = new
                    CreateBucketRequest(BUCKET_NAME);

            Bucket bucket = s3.createBucket(request);

    System.out.println("S3 Hello World completed.");
```

For what it's worth, my compiler cannot find the static `builder()` method, although it is indeed in the API.